# How do I set different settings for different mice?

Tags: mouse

I have two different mice (one is always used on the system, the other is wireless and moves between systems as needed). Unfortunately, the wireless one is much more sensitive than the wired mouse, and the mouse settings panel doesn't seem to have a way to set different settings for different mice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have multiple hardware-specific configurations now, in `/etc/X11/xorg.conf.d/`.

See [X/Config](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/), or [New configuration world order](http://who-t.blogspot.com/2010_01_01_archive.html) which has some more specific examples.

If anyone is interested in helping improve X via wiki editing, a really easy thing to do would be to copyedit the directions at [X/Config](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/) to be in the form of `xorg.conf.d` snippets instead of whole xorg.conf's.  If not, us developers will get to it eventually, but it could save time that developers could then spend on fixing more X bugs.  :-)

Comment: This would be a much more useful answer with an example (or a link to an example).

Comment: Sure, no prob.  Really, it's the same format as xorg.conf so if you've ever had the fortune of editing xorg.conf, you'll know it.  `man xorg.conf` serves as a good reference.  Driver-specific settings can be had via their man pages, e.g. `man intel`, `man evdev`, `man wacom`, et al.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably want to write a simple script that is run automatically or that you run whenever you switch mice. It'll need to simply swap out one config file for another, back and forth whenever it is run.

I don't know which config files this info lives in, or if there's a hook to run scripts when mice are plugged in, but maybe that's a start.

Comment: have a look at `xinput` or udev rules. See https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Config/Input for more information